# Не компилируется LibreOffice в Windows

Tags: windows-7, компиляция, libre-office

Народ пытаюсь откомпилировать LibreOffice в Windows.
Действую по этой [инструкции](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnWindows/ru).

Вот эта команда

```
/cygdrive/c/sources/libreoffice-5.4.1.2/autogen.sh \
               --with-external-tar=/cygdrive/c/sources/lo-externalsrc \
               --with-junit=/cygdrive/c/sources/junit-4.10.jar \
               --with-ant-home=/cygdrive/c/sources/apache-ant-1.9.5 \
              --enable-pch --disable-ccache \
               --disable-activex --disable-atl
```

Выдает следующее

```
Running ./configure with '--with-external-tar=/cygdrive/c/sources/lo-externalsrc --with-junit=/cygdrive/c/sources/junit-4.10.jar --with-ant-home=/cygdrive/c/sources/apache-ant-1.9.5 --enable-pch --disable-ccache --disable-activex --disable-atl --srcdir=/cygdrive/c/sources/libreoffice-5.4.1.2 --enable-option-checking=fatal'
configure: error: unrecognized options: --disable-activex, --disable-atl
Error running configure at /cygdrive/c/sources/libreoffice-5.4.1.2/autogen.sh line 293.
```

А вот эта

```
/cygdrive/c/sources/libreoffice-5.4.1.2/autogen.sh \
               --with-external-tar=/cygdrive/c/sources/lo-externalsrc \
               --with-junit=/cygdrive/c/sources/junit-4.10.jar \
               --with-ant-home=/cygdrive/c/sources/apache-ant-1.9.5 \
               --enable-pch --disable-ccache
```

Выдает следующее:

```
Running ./configure with '--with-external-tar=/cygdrive/c/sources/lo-externalsrc --with-junit=/cygdrive/c/sources/junit-4.10.jar --with-ant-home=/cygdrive/c/sources/apache-ant-1.9.5 --enable-pch --disable-ccache --srcdir=/cygdrive/c/sources/libreoffice-5.4.1.2 --enable-option-checking=fatal'
********************************************************************
*
* Running LibreOffice build configuration.
*
********************************************************************

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking for product name... LibreOfficeDev
checking for package version... 5.4.1.2.0+
checking for product version... 5.4
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for grep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep
checking for GNU Make... C:/cygwin64/opt/lo/bin/make
configure: Using a native Win32 GNU Make version.
checking for explicit COMSPEC... found: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking whether to use link-time optimization... no
checking for explicit AFLAGS... no
checking for explicit CFLAGS... no
checking for explicit CXXFLAGS... no
checking for explicit OBJCFLAGS... no
checking for explicit OBJCXXFLAGS... no
checking for explicit LDFLAGS... no
checking whether build target is Release Build... no
checking whether to sign windows build... no
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gawk... /usr/bin/gawk
checking for bash... /bin/sh
checking for GNU or BSD tar... tar
checking for tar's option to strip components... --strip-components
checking how to build and package galleries... internal src images for desktop
checking whether to build with Java support... yes
checking whether to treat the installation as read-only... no
checking whether to build a 64-bit LibreOffice... no
checking Visual C++... found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\
checking for short pathname of VC product directory... C:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~3/2017/COMMUN~1/VC
checking for UCRT location... cygpath: cannot create short name of Active code page
configure: error: path conversion failed for "Active code page: 65001
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Script "vsdevcmd\ext\Active" could not be found.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10".
Error running configure at /cygdrive/c/sources/libreoffice-5.4.1.2/autogen.sh line 293.
```

Подскажите, кто сталкивался с таким и как решить проблему.

Если в cmd прошу выдать мне *chcp*
отвечает *Active code page 65001*

Пробовал переставить VS в папку без пробелов (посоветовали коллеги) - ничего не изменилось

Comment: А чем готовый exe-шник не устраивает?

Comment: Задача поставлена откомпилировать.

Comment: `configure: error: unrecognized options: --disable-activex, --disable-atl` - ну так предлагаю удалить эти 2 флага из команды...

Comment: Следующая команда в посте так и сделана. --disable-activex, --disable-atl приведены, что бы показать почему я их убрал из инструкции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена частично. Если *cmd* выдаст *Active code page 866* в ответ на *chcp*. То компиляция пройдет успешно.

866 cp должна быть по умолчанию. Как менять это в винде выяснить не удалось. Настройки через реестр из инетов не дали результата - cp консоли все равно оставался 65001.

Компиляция удалась только на другой машине с теми же параметрами, где консоль ответила *Active code page 866*.

Вопрос компиляции на других кодировках не изучен.
Не удалось поставить винду так, что бы консоль была не *866*.
Все дистрибутивы (доступные мне) ставят по умолчанию 866.